# Changing PwdLastSet attribute on AD

Tags: passwords, password-management

I want to test our user password policy by changing a test user's last password change date.
According to our policy, passwords need to be changed every 3 months. So I want to set the date back to 3 months in order to test if the account gets any notification e-mail like "your password is about to expire"

I am new to Active Directory and here also...

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this field accepts user edits, but if so look into ADSIEdit.msc.